# XML API Calls with HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make my inner html contain the result of an API call when there is only one item in the XML doc.

Currently I have only figured out (thanks to W3) how to call when multiple Items exist in the XML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://aaronlilly.github.io/PokeApp/cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the above works, but if i change the "GET" to an XML doc with only one item -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

(data from https://aaronlilly.github.io/PokeApp/cd_catalog2.xml)

I can't get it to work if I change the for loop to an if statement Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, there's no such thing as an if loop, so that's why you can't get that to work... ;) The code should work fine with any number of `CD` nodes.

Comment: If you use a loop then it should work for 0, 1, or 1,000,000 nodes (and onwards). And indeed, it does seem to work fine. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zckhxgyd/ when the data is hard-coded. I wonder if the real issue might be that the XML file you've linked to is not valid - there's an empty line at the start, which isn't allowed. Try opening the link in your browser and you'll see an error. P.S. What is an "if loop" when it's at home??

Comment: I would be interested in hearing the thought process that lead from having code that works for multiple records, to thinking it would not work for just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open up your linked XML file in the browser, you will get an error:

```
error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

Remove the first empty line in your file, so that `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is at the very top.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if a I exactly understand your problem, but you can insert a `if` to check if is a array or not, like it:

```
if(typeof x[0] == 'undefined')
   x = [x];
```

Using your function, the complete code would be:

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  if(typeof x[0] == 'undefined')
    x = [x];
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```